# Undamped oscillations with Lyapunov stability

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, lyapunov-functions

Let $V: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a Lyapunov function for system $\dot{x}=f(x)$. Let $\dot V \leq 0$ hold. Do there exist conditions on th system dynamics such that we can ensure that the system converges to a steady state instead of showing an undamped oscillation?

For example, consider an LC circuit (or equivalently, a mass-spring system) with system dynamics $$ \dot x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} x. $$ We clearly see that there is no damping in any state and thus periodic oscillations occur. If we include damping, i.e. a resistor or friction in the mechanical equivalent), we have damping and the system converges to a steady state instead of undamped oscillations. Can we generalize that and state something like: Lyapunov stability + damping in somestates $\rightarrow$ convergence to a steady state?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with [LaSalle's invariance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle%27s_invariance_principle)?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen yes, but for my example I cannot compute the set $\dot V = 0$ because $\dot V = - (x^\top, z^\top)^\top M (x, z)$, where x and z are state vectors, and M is a 2x2 block matrix for which I cannot compute the kernel. Therefore I was searching for some conditions to avoid undamped oscillations

Comment: @Trb2 Why can't you compute the kernel of $M$? Is the matrix too large? Or are you trying to compute symbolically?

Comment: @SampleTime I am trying to copmute symbolically, i.e. $M$ is a matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^\top & C \end{pmatrix}$ with $A$ pos. def. and $C$ positive semidefinite

Answer (score 1):

In general, no, you cannot conclude that your equilibrium point $x_e$ is asymptotically stable provided $\dot{V}(x) \le 0$ unless by LaSalle's invariance principle, the only trajectory satisfying $\dot{V}(x) = 0$ is $x(t) = x_e$.

In order to use Lyapunov theory to prove $x_e$ is asymptotically stable, you will need to search for another Lyapunov function where $\dot V(x) < 0$ when $x\ne x_e$. There are a few techniques (e.g. replacing $x^Tx$ terms with $x^TPx$ where $P$ is positive definite symmetric matrix in your Lyapunov function and then solving for elements of $P$ to ensure $\dot{V} < 0$, or the variable gradient method) that can help you search for another Lyapunov function. Please refer to Nonlinear Systems by Khalil, Section 4.1 for examples.

There are other, more advanced techniques to prove stability, such as Control Contraction Mapping (CCM), which may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The thing is: I don't want to conclude that the system is asymptotically stable with only by $\dot V \leq 0$, I just want to conclude that it is stable \textbf{and} it converges to some steady state (i.e. it shows no undamped oscillation)

Comment: In nonlinear systems, you never say the system is stable. Only equilibrium points can be stable/unstable. However, if you can find a bounded sublevel set $\Omega_c = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : V(x) \le c\}$ with $\dot{V} \le 0 \forall x \in \Omega_c$ and $x(0) \in \Omega_c$ you can conclude $\Omega_c$ is forward-invariant, hence your trajectory will stay in there for all time, so your trajectory is bounded. Note that all sublevel sets are bounded if your Lyapunov function is *radially unbounded*, meaning $V(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $||x|| \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: you're completely right, sorry for my unprecise comment. However, I still seek some condition such that a system does not show periodic (i.e. undamped) oscillations around a stable equilibrium point. In general, a system may show, around a stable equilibrium, either a periodic oscillation or convergence to a steady state somewhere on a neighborhood of the equilibrium. I am searching for conditions to guarantee that the latter is the case

Comment: Are you asking for conditions for the existence of a limit cycle?

Comment: yes, probably. Or more precisely, conditions for certifying that a limit cycle does not exist for a specific equilibrium of an autonomous system.

Comment: If your system is second-order, you can plot a phase portrait to look for limit cycles. See Nonlinear Systems 3rd Edition, Khalil Chapter 2.6. In the second order case, you could use the Poincare-Bendixson Criterion to prove the existence of a limit cycle (but  you can't use this criterion to show that one does not exist)

Comment: sadly, my system is not a second-order system :/